# Ruby: markup contains utf-8 character

Tags: mysql, ruby, utf-8

**NOTE**: I need to rewrite this question, as I didn't know what I was talking about previously. I am still confusing with encoding.

I have some markup like this in a yml file:

```
"the priestess\xE2\x80\x99s"
"what about \xE2\x80\x9D"
```

The above are UTF-8 (in literal)

I load the yml file by using `File.open(SITE_PATH)` without specifying any encoding method. Then I put the markup into a column in a mysql table. The column's collation is latin1_swedish_ci. (I am not sure why latin1_swedish_ci, but it is always there)

I open up phpmyadmin and find something like priestessÃ¢Â€Â™s

Does anyone has any idea what I should do? (I am using ruby 2.1)

Comment: AFAIK `\xc9` is `É` in all the Latin-N character sets and even Windows-1252 so who knows what happened to your YAML. Do you have any idea what encoding it is supposed to be in or where it came from? Any other instances of apparent nonsense?

Comment: @muistooshort, I need to update my question. It was confusing to me.

Comment: `"\xE2\x80\x99"` is the UTF-8 representation of `’` and `’` has no Latin-1 representation so you'll have to store that string as binary data or fix your database's encoding to be UTF-8.

Comment: @muistooshort I have dropped the table and rebuilt the column with collation with uft8_general_ci. Load the data into column. I still see priestessÃ¢Â€Â™s in phpmyadmin

Comment: Does phpmyadmin understand that it is talking to a UTF-8 database? What if you use the `mysql` shell in a UTF-8 terminal?

Comment: @muistooshort, mysql shell in utf-8 terminal. It shows the same garbage: priestessÃ¢Â€Â™s

Comment: Messes like `Ã¢Â€Â™` are the usual result of confusion about what encoding something is in, someone is confused and is thinking that the text is in encoding X when it is really Y. Go through the process step by step, check the string encoding and display at each step, and see where things stop making sense.